# Parse log and output 2 strings in 1 command

Tags: parsing, awk, grep, logging

```
178.139.20.52 - - [26/Nov/2011:08:21:13 +0000] "POST /test/LinkTest.cgi?e=PATTERN&t3=0:010015&t4=1322295671:587875&l=178.139.20.174&n=149 HTTP/1.1" 200 17 "-" "BOT/1.26"
```

Above is the type of log entry that I want to parse.

I like my command to output:

```
178.139.20.52 PATTERN
```

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Thank you.

Thank you for your answers, I'm going to do this:

```
cat access_log | grep "LinkTest.cgi" | grep "26\/Nov\/2011" | awk -v FS="[ =&]" '{ print $1,$8 }' | sort -u
```

Comment: echo '178.139.20.52 PATTERN'  (IOW, your question is not fully specified.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk:

Content of 'infile'

```
178.139.20.52 - - [26/Nov/2011:08:21:13 +0000] "POST /test/LinkTest.cgi?e=PATTERN&t3=0:010015&t4=1322295671:587875&l=178.139.20.174&n=149 HTTP/1.1" 200 17 "-" "BOT/1.26"
```

Awk command in my linux machine:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "=" } { ip = substr( $1, 0, index( $1, " " ) - 1 ); pattern = substr( $2, 0, index( $2, "&" ) - 1 ); printf "%s %s\n", ip, pattern }' infile
```

Result:

```
178.139.20.52 PATTERN
```

Answer (score 2):

What about this approach using GNU `sed`?

```
sed -r 's/^(\S+).*e=([^&]+)&.*/\1 \2/'
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using `awk`

Note - This would work if your `pattern` does not contain `=`,`space` or `&`.

`awk -v FS="[ =&]" '{ print $1,$8 }' file`

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file
178.139.20.52 - - [26/Nov/2011:08:21:13 +0000] "POST /test/LinkTest.cgi?e=PATTERN&t3=0:010015&t4=1322295671:587875&l=178.139.20.174&n=149 HTTP/1.1" 200 17 "-" "BOT/1.26"


[jaypal:~/Temp] awk -v FS="[ =&]" '{ print $1,$8 }' file
178.139.20.52 PATTERN
```

Comment: This one works perfectly, I indeed cat the file.
cat access_log | grep "LinkTest.cgi" | grep "26\/Nov\/2011" | awk -v FS="[ =&]" '{ print $1,$8 }' | sort -u

Comment: I think you can by-pass `cat` and `grep` by simply doing `awk -v FS="[ =&]" '/26\/Nov\/2011/{ print $1,$8 }' access_log | sort -u` or `uniq` whichever suits the best.

Comment: Actully this is not working, I get :

95.127.96.131 HTTP/1.1"
95.169.240.22 PATTERN

But I'll figure it out.

Comment: Can you paste that line here so that I can take a look at it?

Answer (score 2):

I think grep is not suitable for this, it only filters lines based on a pattern. You can use `-o` switch to only print the text that matched that pattern, but I do not know how can you extract/print multiple substrings in grep.

How about this perl one liner?

`perl -ne 'm/^\s*(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+).+?\?e=([^&]+)/ and print "$1 $2\n"'`

Answer (score 2):

The question seems underspecified, since we don't know what can be in `PATTERN`. Here's a starting point:

```
sed -e 's/ .*LinkTest.cgi?e=/ /' -e 's/&.*//'
```